# How to interpret the raw depth image data?

Tags: ros, primesense, depth-registered

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to get the distance of an object from the depth sensor(Primesense). I am able to subscribe to all the topics. I am not sure which one to use for my purpose. I tried using "/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw" topic.

I have the following information from the topic:

```
Image Height: 480
Image Width: 640
Encoding: 16UC1
Is Big Endian ?: 0
Step: 1280
```

The data looks like this:

```
2  86  2  85  2  85  2  85  2  84  2  84  2  83  2  82  2  82  2  82  2  82  2  82  2  82  2  82  2  82  2  81  2  81  2  81  2  81  2  80  2  80  2  78  2  77  2  75  2  75  2  63  2  63  2  62  2  61  2  60  2  59  2  59  2  58  2  58  2  57  2  57  2  57  2  57  2  56  2  57  2  56  2  57  2  58  2  58  2  58  2  58 ..............
```

But I don't know what these array of bytes indicate. It would be very helpful if someone can teach me How to get the distance from this data?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110996/how-to-interpret-the-raw-depth-image-data?/) by [Keerthi Raj](https://answers.ros.org/users/8061/keerthi-raj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2013-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

It would be easier for you to subscribe to the topic "/camera/depth/points". This topic provides you already with a 3D point cloud extracted from the depth sensor ready to use. The topic's type is [PointCloud2](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/PointCloud2.html) and you can access X, Y and Z values for each point using [PCL](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials).

I hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2013-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5